# Type error when fine-tuning a bert-large-uncased-whole-word-masking model by Huggingface

Tags: bert-language-model, fine-tuning

I am trying to fine-tune a Huggingface bert-large-uncased-whole-word-masking model and i get a type error like this when training:

"TypeError: only integer tensors of a single element can be converted to an index"

Here is the code:

```
train_inputs = tokenizer(text_list[0:457], return_tensors='pt', max_length=512, truncation=True, padding='max_length')
train_inputs['labels']= train_inputs.input_ids.detach().clone()
```

Then i mask randomly about 15% of the words in the input-ids,
and define a class for the dataset, and then the mistake happens in the training loop:

```
class MeditationsDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, encodings):
        self.encodings= encodings
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return {key: torch.tensor(val[idx]) for key, val in self.encodings.items()}
    def __len__(self):
        return self.encodings.input_ids

train_dataset = MeditationsDataset(train_inputs)
train_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset= train_dataset, batch_size=8, shuffle=False)

device = torch.device('cuda') if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.device('cpu')

from transformers import BertModel, AdamW

model = BertModel.from_pretrained("bert-large-uncased-whole-word-masking")
model.to(device)
model.train()

optim = AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=1e-5)
num_epochs = 2
from tqdm.auto import tqdm

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    loop = tqdm(train_dataloader, leave=True)
    for batch in loop:
        batch = {k: v.to(device) for k, v in batch.items()}
        outputs = model(**batch)
        loss = outputs.loss
        loss.backward()

        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
```

The mistake happens in "for batch in loop"

Does anybody understand it and know how to solve this? Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

In the class `MeditationsDataset` in function `__getitem__` 
`torch.tensor(val[idx])` is deprecated by PyTorch you should use instead `val[idx].clone().detach()`